# Servlet Autowire fails

Tags: java, spring, servlets, autowired

I have trouble autowiring some beans in my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/ScoreServlet")
public class ScoreServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
ScoreHandler mScoreHandler;
@Autowired
TransferAdapter mTransferAdapter;

ScoreCreator mScoreCreator;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
    super.init(config);
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
      config.getServletContext());
}
```

if Spring tries to wire `mScoreHandler` I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class de.bc.qz.server.servlet.ScoreServlet]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: de.bc.qz.handler.score.ScoreHandler de.bc.qz.server.servlet.ScoreServlet.mScoreHandler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [de.bc.qz.handler.score.ScoreHandler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>quiz-tomcat</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:META-INF/cmn-dao-spring.xml
            classpath*:META-INF/cmn-serv-spring.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScoreServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.bc.qz.server.servlet.ScoreServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

This is the head of my `ScoreHandler`:

```
@Service
public class ScoreHandler {

@Autowired
private ScoreDao mScoreDao;
```

My JUnit-Test `ScoreHandlerTest` runs very well and without problems. I think it is an issue with `Servlet` and the `Context`.

The ScoreHandler is placed in its own project called cmn-server.
This is the spring config(cmn-serv-spring.xml) of that jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <import resource="cmn-dao-spring.xml" />
    <bean id="scoreHandler" class="de.bc.qz.handler.score.ScoreHandler"
        autowire="byName">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Could you help me find the problem?

Comment: Please post the contents of `serv-spring.xml` and tell us what package `ScoreHandler` is in.

Comment: What container are you using? Is `META-INF` really on the classpath?

Comment: without META-INF I had trouble including the xml files from the jars. with META-INF the start of my local tomcat works fine.

Comment: before tomcat was not able to find the xml's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is hidden in

```
<param-value>
    classpath*:META-INF/cmn-dao-spring.xml
    classpath*:META-INF/cmn-serv-spring.xml
</param-value>
```

If you removed the `*`, you would get a

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [cmn-serv-spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Spring says the following about the `classpath*` prefix

> This special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match
>   the given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens
>   via a ClassLoader.getResources(...) call), and then merged to form the
>   final application context definition.

If it doesn't find anything, it doesn't use (merge) any. [This is explained here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards)

In your case, we can safely assume that `META-INF` is not on the classpath (and it probably shouldn't be) and therefore no files are found and no beans are generated.

I would declare a custom Spring context configuration file and add it to your classpath. Don't rely on other jars.

Comment: @Stefan Those jars will be added to the classpath, but I don't know how the `ClassLoader` handles `META-INF` folders. Try searching for how to add context files from external resources.